# Is there a way i could automate the script in Jenkins with data coming from SQL using AAD

Tags: python, sql, jenkins, azure-active-directory, jenkins-plugins

We have this third party client where we pull the data from SQL using AAD authentication. Below is the way we run in our local systems using Python.

```
server = 'XXX.database.windows.net'
database = 'xxx-production'
username ='xxx'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryPassword'
password = 'xxx'

driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';SERVER='+server+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';PWD='+ password+
                      ';AUTHENTICATION='+Authentication

                      )
df=pd.read_sql(''' select xxxx from tablename.. ''',conn)
```

But we now have to schedule this in Jenkins and seems like AAD is creating a problem.
Is there any way we could schedule it in Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed an Azure SQL DB by enabling **Azure AD login** and set one admin for the DB.

[image]

And I am able to authenticate SQL server with Azure AD locally and get the output of the required table with below code:

[image]
**Output:**

[image]

Now, I have installed **Jenkins** in a Linux VM on Azure and tried to run this script in Jenkins.

I have uploaded the above code in my Git-hub repository so Jenkins server can connect to our Git-hub repo and run the above code.

The above file is added to my **git-hub repo** like below: -

[image]

Now, Let’s head on to Jenkins server and create a Free Style project to run the Python script manually and also schedule it with a CRON expression: -

Run a **Python script** manually: -

- I created a new Item with my repo name
  [image]
- Added a basic description: -
  [image]
- Added my Git repository URL with my credentials and Branch set to python where our project exists: -
  [image]
- As my Jenkins runs on Linux VM in Azure, I have kept the Build set to Execute Shell. If your Jenkins is running on windows machine, you can select Execute Windows batch
  [image]
- Now, I apply these settings Save and run the build, I get my Azure SQL DB table output successfully like below:
  [image]

To **resolve** errors: -

1. Check which machine your Jenkins is running on:
   - If its running on windows machine, Select Execute Windows Batch and write command – python <your-script-name.py
   -  If your Jenkins is running on Linux machine or VM > Select Execute Shell in Build Steps and write command – python3 <your-script-name.py>
2. As our SQL authentication requires ODBC driver,

   ```
   -   First install ODBC driver 17 in your host machine where your Jenkins is running following this link according to your OS: [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server - ODBC Driver for SQL Server | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#documentation)
   - Make sure to install python in your host machine that runs Jenkins. In my lab, I installed python3 in my Ubuntu VM – **sudo apt update** **sudo apt install python3**. If you’re using Windows machine, directly install python from python.org.
   - You need to install and import pip module in your host machine that runs Jenkins, In my lab, I ran
   ```

**sudo apt update**
**sudo apt install python3-pip**
**pip install pyodbc**
[image]

**Schedule the python script: -**

Description to run this Job every 1 minute

[image]

Select **Build** Periodically and write the CRON Expression to schedule your Script.

[image]

I have scheduled the script to run every 1 minute, you can change the CRON expression to set the Build to your required time.

***Build ran successfully every minute:***

[image]

Another Example- ***Auto build every 15 minutes***:

[image]

You change the CRON expressions according to your requirements and schedule the Build.

Instead of using a Free Style Project, you can also build this script with **Pipeline**.